# Pluriharmonic functions are harmonic on submanifolds?

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, complex-geometry, harmonic-functions

Let $X$ a Kähler manifold and $f:X\to \mathbb C$ a function. $f$ is said to be *pluriharmonic* if its restriction to each curve in $X$ is harmonic.

Why is then $f$ harmonic? Does this simply follow from covering $X$ by curves? **Does the same argument then imply that the restriction of $F$ to any complex submanifold of $X$ is harmonic?** (I need to see that $f$ restricted to a special case of compact connected submanifolds is constant, which would follow from harmonicity)

On a similar note, I have seen another of definition of $f$ being pluriharmonic, namely $\partial \overline{\partial} f=0$ Then it follows from a simple calculation that $f$ is harmonic. But how do I see that this definition I equivalent?

Comment: what is your definition of harmonic? are you asking how to prove that the mean equality property is equivalent to $\partial \overline{\partial} f = 0$?

Comment: My definition of harmonic is that $\Delta f=(d d^*+d^*d) f=0$, or equivalently $\sum_i (\frac {\partial^2} {\partial x_i^2} + \frac {\partial^2} {\partial y_i^2})f =0$. 
I am asking why $\partial\overline\partial f=0$ is equivalent to the restriction of $f$ to any curve is harmonic. However, this is not my main question I just have the feeling that this could help me in understanding the main one. @Glougloubarbaki

Comment: up to some constants no one ever remembers right, $\partial \overline{\partial} = \Delta = dd^*+d^*d$. so $\partial \overline{\partial} d=0$ on a curve iff $f$ is harmonic on that curve. and of course $\partial \overline{\partial} f=0$ on $X$ iff $\partial \overline{\partial} f=0$ on every curve

Comment: hm...ok. But what about higher dimension submanifolds? @Glougloubarbaki